# Closure in P-determined topology

Tags: general-topology

#### Notation

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $P$ be a cover of $X$ (i.e. subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcup P = X$), and

$$\mathcal{T}_P = \{U \subset X : \forall C \in P: U \cap C \in \mathcal{T}|C\}.$$

Then $\mathcal{T}_P$ is the [$P$-determined topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology) (a.k.a. the P-coherent topology). The *P-closed* subsets are

$$\mathcal{T}_P^C = \{X \setminus U : U \in \mathcal{T}_P\}.$$

#### Problem

Does it hold that for any $A \subset X$,

$$\overline{A}(\mathcal{T}_P) = \bigcup \{ \overline{A \cap C}(\mathcal{T}|C) : C \in P\}$$

?

Here $\overline{A}(\mathcal{T}_P)$ is a closure in the topology $\mathcal{T}_P$, and $\overline{A \cap C}(\mathcal{T}|C)$ is a closure in the subspace topology $\mathcal{T}|C$.

#### Background

I can prove that the claim holds in the following cases:

- $P \subset \mathcal{T}_P$.
- $P \subset \mathcal{T}_P^C$ and $P$ is $\mathcal{T}_P$-locally finite.

Denoting

$$X' = \bigcup \{ \overline{A \cap C}(\mathcal{T}|C) : C \in P\},$$

these proofs can be sketched as follows:

- We can show $A \subset X'$, since $P$ covers $X$.
- We can show that $\mathcal{T}_P|C = \mathcal{T}|C$. From this it follows that $\overline{A}(\mathcal{T}_P) \supset X'$.
- So if we can show that $X' \in \mathcal{T}_P^C$, then $\overline{A}(\mathcal{T}_P) = X'$.

In the case when $P \subset \mathcal{T}_P$, we have $\overline{A \cap C}(\mathcal{T}_P|C) = \overline{A}(\mathcal{T}_P) \cap C$, which then implies $X' \cap D = \overline{A \cap D}(\mathcal{T}|D) \in \mathcal{T}^C|D$ for each $D \in P$. Therefore $X' \in \mathcal{T}_P^C$.

In the case when $P \subset \mathcal{T}_P^C$ and $P$ is $\mathcal{T}_P$-locally finite, we have $\overline{A \cap C}(\mathcal{T}|C) \in \mathcal{T}^C|C \subset \mathcal{T}_P^C|C \subset \mathcal{T}_P^C$. Then a union of $\mathcal{T}_P$-locally finite set of P-closed subsets is P-closed. Therefore $X' \in \mathcal{T}_P^C$.

Comment: What do you mean by the notation $\mathcal{T}\vert C$?

Comment: The subspace topology of $\mathcal{T}$ on $C$; restriction.